# Table top scoller reverse the content of the table and reverse the up/down key also

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Table scroller on top reverse the table data as total show top but as to change scrollar its shows total in bottom + change the keyboard up and down in reverse order too.

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.table_fixed tbody').scroll(function(e) { 
        $('.table_fixed thead').css("left", -$("tbody").scrollLeft()); //fix the thead relative to the body scrolling
        $('.table_fixed thead th:nth-child(1)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()); //fix the first cell of the header
        $('.table_fixed tbody td:nth-child(1)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()); //fix the first column of tdbody
    });
});
```

```css
.table-degree thead tr th, .table-degree tbody tr td {
    width: 250px;
}
table.table-hover > thead > tr > th {
    border-bottom: 0px !important;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 14px 10px 13px!Important;
}
table.table-hover > thead > tr > th {
    border-bottom: 0px !important;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 14px 10px 13px!Important;
}
.table-degree-scroll {
    overflow-x: auto;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
}
.sum_text {
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.table-degree tbody tr td:first-child, .table-degree thead tr th:first-child {
    text-align: left;
}
.degree-no {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: "roboto-medium";
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 2px;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
.table-degree {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.table-main tr th, .sticky-thead tr th, .sticky-intersect tr th, .sticky-col thead tr th {
    font-family: 'Arial-BoldMT';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #0f0e41;
    padding: 13px 10px 11px!Important;
    border: 1px #fbfbfb solid;
    border-top-color: rgb(251, 251, 251);
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-color: rgb(251, 251, 251);
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom: 0px #ffff solid !important;
    white-space: pre;
}
.sticky-intersect tr th, .sticky-col thead tr th {
    height: 67px;
}
.sticky-enabled tbody tr th.sticky-cell {
    background: #fff !Important;
    color: #373a3c;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}
table.table-hover > thead > tr > th, .sticky-thead > thead > tr > th {
    border-bottom: 0px !important;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 14px 10px 13px!Important;
}
.degree_title {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    color: #000;
}
.container {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-top: 64px;
    min-height: 700px;
}
table.table_fixed {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/*thead*/
table.table_fixed thead {
  position: relative;
  display: block; /*seperates the header from the body allowing it to be positioned*/
  overflow: visible;
 width: 100%;
}

table.table_fixed thead th {
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 70px;
}

table.table_fixed thead th:nth-child(1) {/*first cell in the header*/
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell; /*seperates the first cell in the header from the header*/
    background: #0f0e41;
    z-index: 1;
    outline:1px #fbfbfb solid !Important;
}
table.table_fixed tbody {
  position: relative;
  display: block; /*seperates the tbody from the header*/
  width: 100%;
      height: 460px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
table.table_fixed tbody td {
  min-width: 300px;
}
table.table_fixed tbody tr td:nth-child(1) {  /*the first cell in each tr*/
  position: relative;
  display: block; /*seperates the first column from the tbody*/
  height: 46px;
  background: #fff;
 z-index: 1;
    border-top: 1px red solid;
    border-bottom: 0px red solid;
}
table.table_fixed tbody tr td {
        border-bottom: 1px red solid;
}
table.table_fixed tbody{
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    transform:rotateX(180deg);
}
table.table_fixed thead, table.table_fixed thead tr th, table.table_fixed tbody tr td {
  transform:rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="table-scoller">
<table class="table table-hover table-main table-degree table_fixed" > 
<thead>
<tr> 
<th class="fixed-side" >Name</th> 
<th class="headcol">User Totals<span class="sum_text">(Sum of 1<sup>st</sup> degree to n<sup>th</sup> degree)</span></th>
<th>1st Columns</th> 
<th>2nd Columns</th> 
<th>3rd Columns</th> 
<th>4th Columns</th> 
<th>5th Columns</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody class="scrollContent">
<tr> 
<td data-label="Name" class="fixed-side">Total</td>
<td data-label="User Totals">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">1</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">133</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">140</span>
<span class="degree-black dgrrrrk degree-no">893</span>
</td>

<td data-label="1st degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">1</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">16</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">213</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">229</span>
</td> 
<td data-label="2nd degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">71</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">375</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">446</span>
</td> 
<td data-label="3rd degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">37</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">131</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">168</span>
</td> 
<td data-label="4th degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">8</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">37</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">45</span>
</td> 
<td data-label="5th degree" class="sticky-cell-opposite">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">1</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">4</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">5</span>
</td> 

</tr>
<tr> 
<td data-label="Name" class="fixed-side">Test user 1</td>
<td data-label="User Totals">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">0</span>
</td>
<td data-label="1st degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">0</span>
</td>
<td data-label="2nd degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">0</span>
</td>
<td data-label="3rd degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">0</span>
</td>
<td data-label="4th degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">0</span>
</td>
<td data-label="5th degree" class="sticky-cell-opposite">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">0</span>
</td>

</tr>
<tr> 
<td data-label="Name" class="fixed-side">Test user 2</td>
<td data-label="User Totals">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">0</span>
</td>
<td data-label="1st degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">0</span>
</td>
<td data-label="2nd degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">0</span>
</td>
<td data-label="3rd degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">0</span>
</td>
<td data-label="4th degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">0</span>
</td>
<td data-label="5th degree" class="sticky-cell-opposite">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">0</span>
</td>

</tr>
<tr> 
<td data-label="Name" class="fixed-side">Test user 3</td>
<td data-label="User Totals">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">0</span>
</td>
<td data-label="1st degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">0</span>
</td>
<td data-label="2nd degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">0</span>
</td>
<td data-label="3rd degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">0</span>
</td>
<td data-label="4th degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">0</span>
</td>
<td data-label="5th degree" class="sticky-cell-opposite">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">0</span>
</td>

</tr>
<tr> 
<td data-label="Name" class="fixed-side">Test user 4</td>
<td data-label="User Totals">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">23</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">139</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">162</span>
</td>
<td data-label="1st degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">22</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">22</span>
</td>
<td data-label="2nd degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">13</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">90</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">103</span>
</td>
<td data-label="3rd degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">7</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">24</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">31</span>
</td>
<td data-label="4th degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">3</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">3</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">6</span>
</td>
<td data-label="5th degree" class="sticky-cell-opposite">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">0</span>
</td>

</tr>
<tr> 
<td data-label="Name" class="fixed-side">Test user 5</td>
<td data-label="User Totals">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">23</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">160</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">183</span>
</td>
<td data-label="1st degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">23</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">23</span>
</td>
<td data-label="2nd degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">11</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">90</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">101</span>
</td>
<td data-label="3rd degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">10</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">40</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">50</span>
</td>
<td data-label="4th degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">1</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">7</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">8</span>
</td>
<td data-label="5th degree" class="sticky-cell-opposite">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">1</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">1</span>
</td>

</tr>
<tr> 
<td data-label="Name" class="fixed-side">Test user 6</td>
<td data-label="User Totals">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">1</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">13</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">14</span>
</td>
<td data-label="1st degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">6</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">6</span>
</td>
<td data-label="2nd degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">7</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">7</span>
</td>
<td data-label="3rd degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">1</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">1</span>
</td>
<td data-label="4th degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">0</span>
</td>
<td data-label="5th degree" class="sticky-cell-opposite">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">0</span>
</td>

</tr>
<tr> 
<td data-label="Name" class="fixed-side">Test user 7</td>
<td data-label="User Totals">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">3</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">10</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">13</span>
</td>
<td data-label="1st degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">1</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">5</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">6</span>
</td>
<td data-label="2nd degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">2</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">4</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">6</span>
</td>
<td data-label="3rd degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">1</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">1</span>
</td>
<td data-label="4th degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">0</span>
</td>
<td data-label="5th degree" class="sticky-cell-opposite">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">0</span>
</td>

</tr>
<tr> 
<td data-label="Name" class="fixed-side">Test user 8</td>
<td data-label="User Totals">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">6</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">28</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">34</span>
</td>
<td data-label="1st degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">2</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">14</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">16</span>
</td>
<td data-label="2nd degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">3</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">12</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">15</span>
</td>
<td data-label="3rd degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">1</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">2</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">3</span>
</td>
<td data-label="4th degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">0</span>
</td>
<td data-label="5th degree" class="sticky-cell-opposite">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">0</span>
</td>

</tr>
<tr> 
<td data-label="Name" class="fixed-side">Test user 9</td>
<td data-label="User Totals" >
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">8</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">23</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">31</span>
</td>
<td data-label="1st degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">3</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">12</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">15</span>
</td>
<td data-label="2nd degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">5</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">10</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">15</span>
</td>
<td data-label="3rd degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">1</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">1</span>
</td>
<td data-label="4th degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">0</span>
</td>
<td data-label="5th degree" class="sticky-cell-opposite">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">0</span>
</td>

</tr>
<tr> 
<td data-label="Name" class="fixed-side">Test user 10</td>
<td data-label="User Totals">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">1</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">11</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">52</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">63</span>
</td>
<td data-label="1st degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">1</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">1</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">18</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">19</span>
</td>
<td data-label="2nd degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">7</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">13</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">20</span>
</td>
<td data-label="3rd degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">3</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">15</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">18</span>
</td>
<td data-label="4th degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">5</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">5</span>
</td>
<td data-label="5th degree" class="sticky-cell-opposite">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">1</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">1</span>
</td>

</tr>
<tr> 
<td data-label="Name" class="fixed-side">Test user 11</td>
<td data-label="User Totals">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">14</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">66</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">80</span>
</td>
<td data-label="1st degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">17</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">17</span>
</td>
<td data-label="2nd degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">12</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">28</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">40</span>
</td>
<td data-label="3rd degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">1</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">9</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">10</span>
</td>
<td data-label="4th degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">1</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">12</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">13</span>
</td>
<td data-label="5th degree" class="sticky-cell-opposite">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">0</span>
</td>

</tr>
<tr> 
<td data-label="Name" class="fixed-side">Test user 12</td>
<td data-label="User Totals">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">1</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">11</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">12</span>
</td>
<td data-label="1st degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">1</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">7</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">8</span>
</td>
<td data-label="2nd degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">4</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">4</span>
</td>
<td data-label="3rd degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">0</span>
</td>
<td data-label="4th degree">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">0</span>
</td>
<td data-label="5th degree" class="sticky-cell-opposite">
<span class="degree-gray degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blue degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-green degree-no">0</span>
<span class="degree-blac1 dgrrrrk degree-no">0</span>
</td>

</tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include jQuery.